# Tortoise SVN - Unable to Connect to Repository - No Such Host is Known

Tags: sql-server, svn, connection, tortoisesvn

I am using a Windows 7 64-bit computer on a VPN to access a repository. The majority of the time, I am able to access the repo and update/commit code. However, intermittently, when I attempt to commit or update I receive the error message:

[image: TortoiseSVN Connection Error Message]

In order to allow my self to update/commit anything, I have to go into **Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Change Adapter Settings** and disable/re-enable the Local Area Connection. After the connection to the internet is restored, I am able to update/commit.

Even though I cannot access the repo, I still have internet access and can access the repository using the URL in my browser. It asks me for my credentials and then displays all of the files within the repository. I'm not sure if that means that it is an authorization problem and it can't verify my computer when updating/committing to the repository. However, this connection problem also affects my ability to connect to our database using SQL Server Management Studio.

I am unsure if this is a VPN problem or a credentials issue, or either. Has anyone had similar issues before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, this connection problem also affects my ability to connect to
>   our database using SQL Server Management Studio.

This, and the fact that it work after you reset your networking, cleanly indicates that it's a networking problem (VPN probably). If VPN disconnects are not a problem, try just using IP addresses instead of DNS names when connecting to SVN and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any proxy settings in the TortoiseSVN Settings and set them accordingly.

There is a server file here

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\
```

(simple ini) that may affecting host resolving too.